# How can I build a mobile app that will publish images to ROS?

Tags: android, ros, mobile-application

I'd like to build a simple mobile app that allows the user to click a picture and then publish that picture via a topic to ROS.

How can I connect the app and ROS? What would my development environment look like?

I've tried setting up both Android Studio and ROS2 on a Ubuntu VM, but Android Studio fails to work properly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.